# Convert String to ArrayList

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

Thanks in advance for the help, my code below is taken in a Text File and Displaying it in a ListView, i have Name and youtube in one Line inside the text field.

but what i am looking at trying to do is get the youtube String inside the text file and pass that to my new Activity class as a webview to play the video 
just wondering how can this be done, how can i pass this String into my Setters inside my Model class in order to get an Instance of it, do i need to convert String to ArrayListString ?

```
public class menuFragment extends ListFragment {
    ArrayList<model> songList = new ArrayList<model>();
    public String[] listSongs = new String[]{};
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
        loadSongs();
        return view;
    }
    public void loadSongs() {
        try {
            Resources ResFiles = getResources();
            InputStream ReadDbFile = ResFiles.openRawResource(R.raw.songs);
            byte[] Bytes = new byte[ReadDbFile.available()];
            ReadDbFile.read(Bytes);
            String DbLines = new String(Bytes);
            listSongs = DbLines.split(",");
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listSongs);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), playVid.class);
        model selectedSong = MainController.getInstance().getSongs().get(position);
        i.putExtra("selectedSong", selectedSong);
        startActivity(i);
    }


public class model implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String url;

    public model(String name, String url) {
        this.name=name;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl(){
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }

public class MainController
{
    private static MainController instance;
    private ArrayList<model> songList;
    private MainController()
    {
        this.songList = new ArrayList<model>();
    }
    public static MainController getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = new MainController();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public void addFlight(String name, String singer, String url)
    {
        model f = new model(name,singer,url);
        this.songList.add(f);
    }
    public ArrayList<model> getSongs()
    {
        return this.songList;
    }
```

Comment: Example of your string?

Comment: EdSheeran#http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lp-EO5I60KA,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion class name should be start with capital - Model.

You have only three variables to pass to another activity, so you can have three putExtra with your intent no need for ArrayList, Sir.

```
    Model selectedSong =  MainController.getInstance().getSongs().get(position); 
    i.putExtra("name", selectedSong.getName());
    i.putExtra("singer", selectedSong.getSinger());
    i.putExtra("url", selectedSong.getUrl());
    startActivity(i);
```

And inside onCreate of another Activity, we can access these three values like this way,

```
    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    String name = mIntent.getStringExtra("name");
    String singer = mIntent.getStringExtra("singer");
    String url = mIntent.getStringExtra("url");
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.. when i run the Code i am getting the java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 0. It is pointing to the Model selectedSong = MainController.getInstance.getSongs().get(position) it seems this could be an error due to the fact i dont point my ArrayAdapter to the Model Class ?

Comment: That's because, before you get them by getSongs method, you need to set them with addFlight method. I don't see that in your code.

Comment: Ok Thanks i didn't notice that missing, should i place the addSong into a void method or is there need ?

Comment: I don't know what is addSong and how does it behave?

Comment: What i was hoping to do was when OnItem was Click then call MainController.getInstance().addSong(name,singer,url); but it can not reslove the strings

Comment: Thank you for your Help. I went with a CustomAdapter which seems to work the way i would like it to work.